# Ordinary differential equations (ODEs) - Is there any way to prevent negative values?

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to apply a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) at each spatial grid cell. Thus, each landscape cell has an associated ODE model. The number of susceptible mosquitoes (`Sv`), exposed mosquitoes (`Se`) and infected mosquitoes (`St`) are updated at each time step and the ODE model is coupled with an discrete agent-based model of animal movement. Here is an example to run the ODE model:

```
library(deSolve)

mod1 <- function(out_tab, time_step, var){
 Sv <- out_tab[time_step,c("Sv")]
  Ev <- out_tab[time_step,c("Ev")]
  Iv <- out_tab[time_step,c("Iv")]

  Nh <- out_tab[time_step,c("Nh")]
  Ih <- out_tab[time_step,c("Ih")]
  bv <- 100
  dv <- 0.07
  betav <- 0.33
  av <- 0.5
  muv <- 0.1

  mod <- function(times, states, parameters) {
    with(as.list(c(states, parameters)), {

      dSv <- bv - dv*Sv - betav*av*(Ih/Nh)*Sv
      dEv <- betav*av*(Ih/Nh)*Sv - dv*Ev - muv*Ev
      dIv <- muv*Ev - dv*Iv

      return(list(c(dSv, dEv, dIv)))

    })
  }

  states <- c(Sv = Sv, Ev = Ev, Iv = Iv)
  input_parameters <- c(bv = bv, dv = dv, betav = betav, av = av, muv = muv)

  ## Solve ODEs
  out <- ode(func=mod, y=states, times=seq(time_step, time_step + 1, by=1), parms=input_parameters, method="iteration")
  out <- as.data.frame(out)

  out_tab[time_step + 1, c("Sv", "Ev", "Iv")] <- out[dim(out)[1], c("Sv", "Ev", "Iv")]
  # out_tab[time_step + 1, c("Nh")] <- var
  # out_tab[time_step + 1, c("Ih")] <- var

  return(out_tab)

}
out_tab <- data.frame(Sv = 10, Ev = 3, Iv = 2, Nh = 2, Ih = 1)
Nh <- c(5, 1, 8, 0, 5)
Ih <- c(2, 0, 4, 0, 1)

for(time in 1:2){
  out_tab <- mod1(out_tab = out_tab, time_step = time)
  ## print(out_tab)
  out_tab[time + 1, c("Nh")] <- Nh[time + 1]
  out_tab[time + 1, c("Ih")] <- Ih[time + 1]
}
```

At `time = 2` (in days), `Ih` (number of animals in a cell) is equal to 0 so that the value for `Ev` is negative. Is there any way to prevent negative values from ODEs? I used the Method `"iteration"` because the ODE model is incorporated in a discrete agent-based model.

Comment: When I run your code I get the error `could not find function "ode"` so I'm left to guess that you are using a package that you didn't tell us about.

Comment: @ngm It requires the `deSolve` package.

Comment: Sometimes there are options in the solver to indicate positiveness. Sometimes you need a better solver, most implicit ones should work well. And sometimes you force `x` being positive by substituting `x=exp(u)`.

Comment: @ngm sorry I have added the package in the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few major issues here; to cut a long story short you have defined your model system incorrectly to use with `method = "iteration"`, so no amount of light tinkering will get you sensible results. I'll get to this in the second part of my answer, but first, I'll answer your original question.

### Using Events to Obtain Non-Negative State Values

You can force non-negative population sizes in `deSolve` using **events**. I suggest you read the `deSolve` documentation further, as there are many ways to trigger events, but we'll integrate one into your code that is triggered during each time step. Because it is time-based, it'll need some sort of maximum time to refer to, so I've created a `maxtime` value that you can also use in your for-loop. You should define this value somewhere accessible to your other functions; I simply put it before your `mod1` function declaration.

```
# Here we declare the maximum time to which your system will evaluate
maxtime <- 2

# This is where we define your event function
# Add this directly above your call to ode()
  posfun <- function(t, y, parms){
    with(as.list(y), {
      y[which(y<0)] <- 0  
      return(y)
    })
  }

# Here's your original call to ode(), with a small addition
# Notice that we added events; iteration is missing, more on that later
  out <- ode(func=mod, 
             y=states, 
             times=seq(time_step, time_step + 1, by=1), 
             parms=input_parameters, 
             events=list(func = posfun, time = c(0:maxtime)))
  
  out <- as.data.frame(out)

# Don't forget to add maxtime to your for-loop
for(time in 1:maxtime){
  out_tab <- mod1(out_tab = out_tab, time_step = time)
  ## print(out_tab)
  out_tab[time + 1, c("Nh")] <- Nh[time + 1]
  out_tab[time + 1, c("Ih")] <- Ih[time + 1]
```

Looking at `posfun`, we see that it simply checks each of our state variables at each time step, and sets any negative values to zero. If we check our output we see it gives us non-negative population densities:

```
 out_tab
        Sv       Ev       Iv Nh Ih
1  10.0000  3.00000 2.000000  2  1
3 179.7493 16.67784 3.244288  1  0
4 416.2958 10.01499 6.133576  8  4
```

Great, right? Well, not quite. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to use events when `method = iteration`. Given what you've shared about your model so far, there are certainly arguments for modelling it in continuous time. Just because dispersal events are discretized does not necessarily mean that birth, death, and infection events must be discrete as well. It is important to conceptualize the different timescales at which these phenomena are occurring in real life, and ask yourself whether or not you are capturing them accurately with your model. However, this is already getting beyond the scope of StackOverflow, so on to the second part:

### Coding discrete-time models into R with deSolve

Looking at the documentation for the `iteration` method in `deSolve`, we see that: *"Method "iteration" is special in that here the function func should return the new value of the state variables rather than the rate of change."*

You have clearly coded in a continuous-time model that returns the value of *derivatives*, and not a discrete-time model that returns the value of your *state variables*. Your birth component in `dSv` is a bare constant, so you are using an intrinsic birth *rate*; in a discrete-time model your birth component would be some constant *number* of offspring (almost always an integer) multiplied by the number of "parents" from the previous timestep.

Looking at your system of equations, we can see how this creates a problem: **Instead of having each individual of `Sv` give birth to 100 individuals at each time step, you are *setting* `Sv` to 100.** It is inevitable that `Sv` will plummet down past zero as you quickly accumulate a net loss.

An example discrete-time model would look something like:

```
# discrete-time host-parasite model
Parasite <- function(t, y, ks) {
P <- y[1]
H <- y[2]
f <- A * P / (ks + H)
Pnew <- H * (1 - exp(-f))
Hnew <- H * exp(rH * (1 - H) - f)
list (c(Pnew, Hnew))
}
```

Notice how we constantly refer to the "present" values of P and H in order to calculate their population dynamics for the next time step. I hope this has been helpful to you, and I wish you luck with your modelling adventures!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much Marcus!  Would it correct to use another solver (e.g. Euler, fourth order Runge-Kutta)? In this case, does the function return a new value of the state variable or the value of derivatives? Thanks for your time

Comment: No problem Nell - I had a lot of fun looking into this! Yes, if you use a continuous-time solver like Euler or rk4, your model evaluates properly. I checked this myself after I coded the events in. Using the Euler method, the plots of your population dynamics looked fine.

If you use continuous-time methods, you can leave your equation unchanged, as they return the value of the new derivatives. I originally wanted to add some plots in to show this behaviour, but the answer was already getting quite long...I decided to keep what I felt was the most pertinent information. I hope this helps!

Comment: I would need to have the values of state variables from my continuous-time model. Are there other solvers allowing to return the state variables from continuous-time models ? Or How can I convert my continuous-time model into a discrete-time model ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: "euler" is a **discrete** time solver intended to approximate continuous time if the time step is small. So, it can of course be used for discrete time models. The difference to "iteration" is that the model must return the derivative (difference) for euler, but the new state for iteration.